# Theano Reshaping

Tags: reshape, theano

I am unable to clearly comprehend `theano`'s `reshape`. I have an image matrix of shape:

```
    [batch_size, stack1_size, stack2_size, height, width]
```

, where there are `stack2_size` stacks of images, each having `stack1_size` of channels. I now want to convert them into the following shape:

```
    [batch_size, stack1_size*stack2_size, 1 , height, width]
```

such that all the stacks will be combined together into one stack of all channels. I am not sure if reshape will do this for me. I see that reshape seems to not lexicographically order the pixels if they are mixed in dimensions in the middle. I have been trying to achieve this with a combination of `dimshuffle`,`reshape` and `concatenate`, but to no avail. I would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: This operation works exactly as it should, I have used it many a time. Assume C-ordering for the reshaping operations and everything should be explainable. If you have a specific issue with how it behaves, you need to expose it by providing a working example and stating what you think is wrong.

Comment: For example, for the above setup, will I be able to use `x.reshape((batch_size,tack1_size*stack2_size, 1 , height, width))` ? If so will that change the lexicographic arrangement ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Theano reshape](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.reshape) works just like [numpy reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with its default `order`, i.e. `'C'`:

> ‘C’ means to read / write the elements using C-like index order, with
>   the last axis index changing fastest, back to the first axis index
>   changing slowest.

Here's an example showing that the image pixels remain in the same order after a reshape via either numpy or Theano.

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor


def main():
    batch_size = 2
    stack1_size = 3
    stack2_size = 4
    height = 5
    width = 6
    data = numpy.arange(batch_size * stack1_size * stack2_size * height * width).reshape(
        (batch_size, stack1_size, stack2_size, height, width))
    reshaped_data = data.reshape([batch_size, stack1_size * stack2_size, 1, height, width])
    print data[0, 0, 0]
    print reshaped_data[0, 0, 0]

    x = theano.tensor.TensorType('int64', (False,) * 5)()
    reshaped_x = x.reshape((x.shape[0], x.shape[1] * x.shape[2], 1, x.shape[3], x.shape[4]))
    f = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=reshaped_x)
    print f(data)[0, 0, 0]


main()
```